# How to Create New Case in Salesforce from third-party web application using API

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud

We have a web application that users log into and consume our products. From this application, we'd like to have a form that users can submit to create cases in our Salesforce instance. I'm looking for a REST API endpoint that I can POST the new case information to, which will then create a new case record in Salesforce. I'm a little confused on the right way to approach this based on the Salesforce docs (Apex, Lightning Platform, Force.com, etc.). Has anyone implemented this or can share the right approach?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to would be to create a [force.com site](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sites_overview.htm&type=5), which is essentially a visualforce page. Your page can then use a controller to read values and create Cases.

For e.g. this visualforce page updates a custom object record by using id passed in url:

```
<apex:page controller="MyService"></apex:page>

@RestResource(urlMapping='/myservice')

global class MyService {
    @HttpGet
    global static void doGet() {
      RestContext.response.addHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
        String id = RestContext.request.params.get('id');
        abc__c veh = [select name, abc__c from abc__c where id =:id];
        if(veh!=null)
        {
          veh.abc__c = true;
          try {
            update veh;
          } catch (DMLException e) {
            RestContext.response.responseBody = Blob.valueOf('DML ERROR');
          }
          RestContext.response.responseBody = Blob.valueOf('OK');
        }
        else
          RestContext.response.responseBody = Blob.valueOf('FAIL');
    }
}
```